# Why does tomcat-admin install require adding admin and manager to tomcat-users.xml manually?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, tomcat6

I installed tomcat6 on lucid using apt-get. All working.

I installed tomcat-admin. Not working.

I amended the `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` file to uncomment the users and roles (from the default) to be like the following:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="password" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="password" roles="role1"/>
```

This still didn't work.

Then from the following [page](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1087957) I added.

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="secret" roles="manager"/>
```

then it worked.

Why doesn't this occur as part of the install? (Why isn't this in the [Ubuntu Manual on Tomcat](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html) ?)

Comment: The [Ubuntu Manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html#tomcat-installation-admin) has: *"Access to the manager application is protected by default: you need to define a user with the role "manager" in /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml before you can access it."* I stumbled upon this myself several times, i thing many people are missing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansered in the comments.

> The Ubuntu Manual has: "Access to the manager application is protected by default: you need to define a user with the role "manager" in /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml before you can access it." I stumbled upon this myself several times, i thing many people are missing it...